# How can I change from a list of dictionaries to a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries and a list of lists.

```
dataset = [{'': 0, 'FAILED': 412.698, 'PASSED': 587.301},
           {'': 440, 'FAILED': 31.746, 'PASSED': 968.253},
           {'': 880, 'FAILED': 253.968, 'PASSED': 746.031},
           {'': 1320, 'FAILED': 714.285, 'PASSED': 285.714}]

data_orders = [['', 'FAILED', 'PASSED'],
               ['', 'FAILED', 'PASSED'],
               ['', 'PASSED', 'FAILED'],
               ['', 'PASSED', 'FAILED']]
```

Then, I want to change a list of dics into two list of tuples based on data_orders like this.

```
FAILED = [(0, 412.698), (440, 471.746), (1626.031, 1879.999), (1605.714, 2319.999)]
PASSED = [(412.698, 999.999), (471.746, 1439.999), (880, 1626.031), (1320, 1605.714)]
```

If you look at the first list of 'data_orders', the elements are ['', 'FAILED', 'PASSED'] The first tuple of list 'FAILED' is (0, 412.968). 
The third tuple of list 'FAILED' are related to the third list of 'data_orders, so the third tuple of list 'FAILED' will be (1626.031(880+746.031), 1879.999(1626.031+253.968)).

'Cause I am not good at English, so I'm afraid that I explained a little too lengthy.
Can anybody let me know how to code?

Comment: What is your own code for this problem? What did you try?

Comment: Could you explain the logic in more detail? Why is a "passed" value of 746.031 used to derive the value 1626.031 in `FAILED`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I'm not really sure what your code is doing, but this gives the required output. It is a bit messy, and could be simplified I'm sure, but hopefully it will help you understand what your problem is, and how you might go about solving it in a nicer fashion!

```
dataset = [{'': 0, 'FAILED': 412.698, 'PASSED': 587.301},
           {'': 440, 'FAILED': 31.746, 'PASSED': 968.253},
           {'': 880, 'FAILED': 253.968, 'PASSED': 746.031},
           {'': 1320, 'FAILED': 714.285, 'PASSED': 285.714}]

data_orders = [['', 'FAILED', 'PASSED'],
               ['', 'FAILED', 'PASSED'],
               ['', 'PASSED', 'FAILED'],
               ['', 'PASSED', 'FAILED']]

FAILED = []
PASSED = []     
for dataset_row,data_order_row in zip(dataset,data_orders):
    if data_order_row[1] == 'FAILED':
        FAILED.append((dataset_row[''],dataset_row['FAILED']+dataset_row['']))
        PASSED.append((dataset_row['FAILED']+dataset_row[''],dataset_row['FAILED']+dataset_row['']+dataset_row['PASSED']))
    else:
        FAILED.append((dataset_row['']+dataset_row['PASSED'],dataset_row['FAILED']+dataset_row['']+dataset_row['PASSED']))
        PASSED.append((dataset_row[''],dataset_row['']+dataset_row['PASSED']))


soln_failed = [(0, 412.698), (440, 471.746), (1626.031, 1879.999), (1605.714, 2319.999)]
soln_passed = [(412.698, 999.999), (471.746, 1439.999), (880, 1626.031), (1320, 1605.714)]

print FAILED == soln_failed
print PASSED == soln_passed
```